# codeigniter routing multiple params

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to create a single rule for routing that will accept any of the following

```
domain.com/backend/controller
domain.com/backend/controller/var
domain.com/backend/controller/var/var/etc
```

I want to automatically determine the controller from the url and be able to work no matter how many params are in the url

```
$route['backend/(:any)/(.*)'] = "admin/$1";
```

So one rule, that will mean that

```
domain.com/backend/members
domain.com/backend/members/var
domain.com/backend/members/var/var/etc
```

and

```
domain.com/backend/blogs
domain.com/backend/blogs/var
domain.com/backend/blogs/var/var/etc
```

will all locate the correct controller and forward have every other param availabe using

```
$this->uri->segment(x)
```

Comment: That's weird. Do you really need that ?

Can you explain what you want, maybe there's a better way ;)

Comment: I think you can do like $route['backend/(:any)'] = "admin/$1";
$route['backend/(:any)/(:any)'] = "admin/$1/$2";
$route['backend/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "admin/$1/$2/$3"; etc.

Comment: @Maxime I am trying to have a situation where I can throw any number of params to a given controller and not get 404 errors. wihout hardcoding each eventuallity as user3470953 has suggested. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: first option, is it really necessary to pass data by url ? because for example if you pass data by json, you could have as many var as you want :) Tell me if it's not the case

Answer (score 0):

you can use uri class, in routes

```
$route['backend/(:any)'] = "admin/index";
```

in controller:

```
$n = $this->uri->total_rsegments() //gets total number of segments

$segs = $this->uri->segment_array(); //Returns an array containing the URI segments.

foreach ($segs as $segment) 
{
  echo $segment;
  echo '<br />';
}
```